# Gson error: Failed to invoke protected java.util.AbstractCollection() with no args

Tags: java, json, gson

I made some massive changes to a json file in my project and now Gson is complaining with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.util.AbstractCollection() with no args
```

The json source file can [be found here](http://hastebin.com/udeqadoyix.json).

My implementation for the corresponding object can [be found here](http://hastebin.com/efeniyugip.java)

I'm firing up Gson like this:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), Config.class);
```

The source file that integrates Gson can [be found here](http://hastebin.com/igifizofaj.java)

I did some scrubbing around on SO and I found this article but the links were broken so I couldn't really get a grip on the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351720/deserializing-a-custom-object-with-gson-error-failed-to-invoke-public-custom-cla

The only thing I think *could* be causing the issue is this block of code found in `Config.java:91`

```
private AbstractCollection<String> expectedMessages = null;

    public Structure() {
        if(this.messagesInOrder) {
            this.expectedMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            this.expectedMessages = new HashSet<>();
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure why it would be causing the error since you can do this normally. Perhaps Gson doesn't construct a new instance of the inner class?

Here's the stack trace for reference

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.util.AbstractCollection() with no args
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:78)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    at config.ParseConfig.convertJsonToObject(ParseConfig.java:70)
    at config.ParseConfig.parseConfig(ParseConfig.java:36)
    at JavaGrader.main(JavaGrader.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:104)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently this works:

```
private Set<String> expectedMessages = new HashSet<>();
// remove CTOR
```

I guess it was an issue with Gson not constructing a new instance of the class? I suppose if someone has a good explanation then I'd like to know!